# PrimeFaces components are not recognized and don't render

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I just added PrimeFaces 3.0 to a JSF project:

```
<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I created this test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:panel header="F.C. Barcelona" footer="Visca el Barca!">
                <h:outputText value="FC Barcelona " />
            </p:panel>

            <h:outputText id="name" value="#{facesBean.name}" />                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{facesBean.callService()}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

But the `<p:panel>` component is not rendered. Only the `<h:xxx>` components are properly rendered.

I have PrimeFaces jar in Maven dependecies and in the target folder. I'm using Tomcat 7. PrimeFaces doesn't need any additional configuration, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

This XML namespace is for PrimeFaces 2.x only. Since PrimeFaces 3.0, the new XML namespace is

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Make sure that you're reading documentation/tutorials concerning PrimeFaces 3.0, not 2.x.